# Transfer two variables between three methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, methods

How would I go about sending a int variable, and string variable from one method to another method, to a final third method? This is basically how I have my methods setup. Obviously there is code that runs in each of these, but I am just trying to understand how to transfer these variables to my other methods.

```
    protected void deleteOkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        remove()
    }

    protected void imgdelbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void remove()
    {

    }
```

Comment: What's the scope of these variables. Are they something unique to each user's session, or something that can be tracked at a more global level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [hidden field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) control on the page.

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="MyHiddenValue" runat="server" />
```

And then set it and reference it within (almost) any event in your code-behind:

```
protected void imgdelbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyHiddenValue.Value == "BAM!")
    {
        // Stuffs...
    }
}
```

Comment: And as Chuck mentioned, ViewState is an option.

Answer (score 0):

In your delete method raise an event `MyCustomEvent` that takes `MyCustomEventArgs` which contains the fields that you want to pass to another class.

Then, have that other class hook a handler into this classes event.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling from method1 to method2 to method 3?  Or are they each called by user events?

Given that you call them, but don't want to change parameter names, you could create a structure and send it as the sender object then cast it back to the structure, or create a new class that extends EventArgs and pass them there.

If the are called by user events and you want to share the values, then global values would be the way to go, or as Kon comments, that this may be an asp.net page, then you'd use ViewState to hold the values between postbacks.

A sample use of ViewState would look like:

```
public uint ClauseId
{
    get { return Convert.ToUInt32(ViewState["ClauseId"] ?? 0); }
    set { ViewState["ClauseId"] = value; }
}
```

Then in your methods you could access ClauseId as a property of the page.

Ps, I just copied this from some code.  The names in quotes can be anything you want, just be the same for reading and writing, and it can be different than the property name.  You also don't have to use a property, I just find it easier to read if accessed multiple places than reading and writing directly to ViewState in methods.